# Blender CAD commands

Tags: modeling, mesh, add-on

Is there a way in Blender to achieve some CAD commands like extend lines to the intersection (or nearest) point, or trim/extend to plane?

Like this:
http://www.qcad.org/doc/qcad/2.2/reference/en/chapter28.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifically for the commands you mention there exists a CAD add-on called [mesh tinyCAD](https://github.com/zeffii/mesh_tinyCAD), allows you to easily do the following things (this is not an exhaustive list):

- VTX (like `_extend`):

  - automatically extend edges towards their projected intersection
  - generate a vertex at the intersection of two edges  ("weld")
- V2X:

  - generate an unattached vertex at the projected intersection of two edges
- XALL:

  - intersects all selected edges.
- BIX:

  - generates the bisector of two selected edges
- CCEN:

  - given any three selected vertices (in one object), this can recreate a circular set of vertices of any number and scale.

For questions about the add-on or ideas use the project's [issue tracker](https://github.com/zeffii/mesh_tinyCAD/issues)

---

For `_fillet` you can use [the bevel command](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/bevel.html): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> With 1 vertex selected

- It starts out as a *bevel* but you can increase the number of segments to turns it into a *fillet*.
- Adjust radius

Comment: There are also some built-in features in Blender, which come in handy. Vertex/Edge slide for example can be used to move a vetex / edge by a factor of 0.5 for the midpoint. Turn off clamping to extend. Snapping does unfortunately not work while sliding.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new Addon called **CAD transform**, that goes well with other commands as well. Have a look here

https://blenderartists.org/t/cad-like-transform/1226197

It can be found on [the authors gumroad page](https://gumroad.com/blender_archipack).